# MS Excel 2010 displays wrong values and characters

Tags: java, excel

Hello
I have a java code which has export functionality.
If I open that excel sheet with Open Office, everything is displayed as expected.
But when I open the same file in MS Excel 2010, some dates are displayed as "#" and a text column does not display the expected name, but rather it displays "#NAME?".
And this happens only with some rows.  Some rows displays date and text as expected but rest displays "#" and "#NAME?".

What does "#" and "#NAME?" mean and is there any way to avoid this ?

Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am not sure why you tagged java with this question?

OK MS Office Excel display #NAME when the it does not find the correct field specified in the cell or formula is missing.

See MS document for full details [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/correct-a-name-error-HP005203939.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Excel will sometimes display hashes for dates if the column is too thin to show the entire date, so the width of the column might be an issue too.

I'd also check the format of the formula - OpenOffice by default uses a semicolon to separate arguments, where Excel uses a comma. If you're saving in native Excel format, this might be an issue.